# Theta-subsumption

Tags: machine-learning

I am confused as to where 5 and 7 would fit into the hierarchy.

[image]

From my limited understanding of theta-subsumption I have the following:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to DS Stack Exchange. What is the original paper?

Comment: @NicolasMartin this is just a practice exam question

Comment: Ok thanks. Where do 5 and 7 come from? Or is it the full question?

Comment: This is the full question, in red is what I could figure out about their generality, but am still not sure if that is even correct.